# Where to store counters in Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have a `Countries` collection and inside this collection, There are 195 countries, and the admin can add or delete any country.

In my Android app, I want to know how many countries are currently there without reading all countries again because that will cost me 195 reads for each user, so I decided to create a counter for this but the question is where should I put the counter? Should I create a new collection for just that counter?

Comment: I think you might also be interested in reading this article, [How to count the number of documents in a Firestore collection?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-count-the-number-of-documents-in-a-firestore-collection-3bd0c719978f).

Comment: @AlexMamo I read your article already before posting this topic and your article is helpful but the question is repeated where should I create the counter field for the countries? I spent 3 days for think about this issue and I hope to find a way soon. What about creating a new document called `Counter Of Countries` and inside it put the counter field? I'm really confused!

Comment: Yes, as already Frank van Puffelen mentioned in his answer, that solution will work. Add a document in a collection and keep the corresponding counters.

Comment: @AlexMamo Okay, I'll do that, But when I want to get all countries the first time can I get all documents except the `Counter Of Countries` document, Or that not possible?

Comment: If the counter document is located in another collection, why not? Otherwise, you should exclude that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no singular correct answer for this, so I'll illustrate some patterns I've seen used instead.

The [distributed counter](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/counters) example in the documentation stores the counter documents in a top-level `shards` collection. That's a good starting point, although I'd probably name it something like `metadata` or `counters`.

In the Cloud Functions example of a [child node counter](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/main/child-count/README.md) for Realtime Database, we store the counter as a sibling property of the node that holds the children. So you have `likes` (which hold the actual likes) and `likes_count`, which is the counter. In Firestore that structure could also work if the count isn't global, but you're counting a subcollection of a specific document.

Finally, I did some experimenting with geo-indexes myself a while ago, and there I put my counter documents in the same collection as the documents they counted, but then with a predictable name. The documents had prefix-based IDs, so I ended up with count documents `geodocs-2 counts`, `geodocs-3 counts`, etc.

Each of these is a good practice for the use-case in question, and can likely be applied to many other use-cases as well. But I'm guessing there are many more reasonable, workable strategies for other cases too.

Comment: I think for me I'll create a document inside the `Countries` collection and name it `The Counter` and inside it, I'll create the field, Is it good practice? To be honest, I don't know why the Firebase team doesn't create a function that can count the documents without much cost, This will be useful for a lot of developers. Can I know the reason?